# Very Basic Password form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords, submit

I need some help as when anything is typed in nothing comes at the output. Just so that you are aware... l am VERY new to websites and l have spent most of this morning trying to figure this out and can't get round it. Thank you Steve

Requested Explanation: the page is www........co.uk/contact.html

When l submit the form with text in the filed or with no text in the field and click "submit". The field empties (goes blank) the page

refreshes and shows in the address bar www........co.uk/contact.html#

Which displays the exact same content of www........co.uk/contact.html

and yes, the filed is still empty here on www........co.uk/contact.html#

Basically refreshes the page adding # on the end

HTML:

```
 <form  name = "login" method = "post" action = "check.php" > 
    <input type = "password" name = "pass">
    <input type = "submit" value = "login" style="color:white; background: blue"> &nbsp &nbsp
    </form>
```

PHP password check page

```
<?php
if   ($_POST['pass']  ==  "pass123") 

   {
       header("Location: http://www.example-correct.co.uk"); 
   }


 else

  {
     header("Location: http://www.example-wrong.co.uk"); 
  }

?>
```

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of your page below `<?php` -- this will tell you what is being received from your form.

Comment: I have just tired that and it wont work :/

Comment: @SteveKevin "nothing comes at the output" and "it won't work" aren't very descriptive. Please tell us what's actually happening when submitting the form.

Comment: Are you sure ur php file is .php?

Comment: the page is www........co.uk/contact.html

When l submit the form with text in the filed or with no text in the field and click "submit". The field empties (goes blank) the page

refreshes and shows in the address bar www........co.uk/contact.html#

Which displays the exact same content of www........co.uk/contact.html

and yes, the filed is still empty here on www........co.uk/contact.html#

Comment: Basically refreshes the page adding # on the end

Comment: If it is just refreshing to `/contact.html#` instead of going to `/check.php`, then you may some javascript preventing the form submission, or there are some errors in your page code so the form is not submitting properly. Based off your sample code, it should be going to `check.php`.

Comment: yes, you are correct @Sean

Comment: can you post the full code of `contact.html`. There may be some unclosed elements, or other issues outside the form causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the password field to be filled after submission, you need to change the form page from `.html` to `.php`, and redirect to your original form page instead of `check.php`.

```
<input type = "password" name = "pass" <?php if(isset($_POST['pass'])) { echo 'value="'.$_POST['pass'].'"'; } ?>>
```

If the user put in the wrong password, instead of redirecting to another page, you want to show the same page and produce an error message, then display the form again so they can put in the correct password.

this is your new contact.php

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if($_POST['pass'] == 'pass123') {
            header('location: http://www.example-correct.co.uk');
        } else {
            echo 'wrong pass';
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form  name = "login" method = "post" action = "contact.php" > 
        <input type = "password" name = "pass" <?php if(isset($_POST['pass'])) { echo 'value="'.$_POST['pass'].'"'; } ?>>
        <input type = "submit" value = "login" style="color:white; background: blue"> &nbsp &nbsp
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

of course, echoing the password after submission doesn't do much because it's nothing but bullets (and I never echo the pass) but this example shows you how it's done. You can also use a separate form processing page and `include()` it after submission, but that's a little more complicated. This is an easier example.

EDIT: updated code example, fixed a bug.

Comment: Is the bottom part the full .php or do l split it after ?> and save the <?php ......?> enslode part as check.php and put the <html> to </html> part in my website page <div.>

Comment: No, just use this instead of `contact.html` and `check.php`. This replaces both of them. Create a new file named `contact.php`, past this code into it and fill out/submit the form to see it in action.

Comment: And the " name = "pass"  line you wrote at the top goes straight into the div on my HTML page? just wanted to check. Thanks. I've done the php file now.

Comment: No, forget about your `contact.html` and `check.php` pages. Create a new file on the server and name it `contact.php`, copy my code above (i've updated it) and paste it into `contact.php`. Visit `contact.php` in your browser and submit the form.

Comment: That makes perfect sence

Comment: Now you have a page with both `PHP` and `HTML` in it so it can do double duty! :) Of course, my code is extremely basic, so you'll want to edit it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Tim, l have one html form which l would like to use that l have. Would it work with you php code? I can add in the necessary check line for username myself in the .php file. HTML login form jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/New_to_Websites/5A4vS/6/

Comment: You're welcome. :) Yeah, it would work. Any form will work, really; it's just a matter of using the right code in the right spots. I rarely use files with a `.html` extension anymore, because using `.php` is just so much more flexible. Forms are a big, complicated subject, you might want to check out Lynda.com and watch a few movies on forms. i just watched one a couple weeks ago as a refresher and picked up a couple new things :)